# Losing formatting using "echo -e" in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having a problem with the following snippet:

```
while read line
do
     team1=`echo "${line% *}"`
     team2=`echo "${line#* }"`
     newline=`printf "%-8.2f\t%-8.2f\n" "$team1" "$team2"`
     #this line give perfect output
     # echo "$newline" 
     ##################problem is here########################
     final_list=("${final_list[@]}" "$newline")
     #########################################################
done <input.txt

#this line is losing all the formatting I gave
echo -e ${final_list[@]} | sort -t$'\t' -k1 -nr
```

This is my input file

```
3.01 16.12
1.12 13.22
3.01 14.12
```

My expected output is

```
1.12            13.22   
3.01            14.12   
3.01            16.12
```

Comment: If you are actually using `bash`, the `echo` is unnecessary in your assignment: `team1=${line% *}` and likewise for `team2`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you, it really makes more sense

Comment: Note that `final_list=("${final_list[@]}" "$newline")` could be written `final_list+=("$newline")`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
echo -e ${final_list[@]} | sort -t$'\t' -k1 -nr
```

with:

```
printf "%s\n" "${final_list[@]}" | sort -t$'\t' -k1 -n
```

This achieves your expected output:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${final_list[@]}" | sort -t$'\t' -k1 -n
1.12            13.22   
3.01            14.12   
3.01            16.12
```

There were two required changes.  First, `sort` works line-by-line and the `echo` output produces a single line.  Second, because your desired output was numerically sorted in ascending order, the `-r` flag needed to be removed from `sort`.

#### What went wrong

This line does not do what one would think:

```
 newline=`printf "%-8.2f\t%-8.2f\n" "$team1" "$team2"`
```

The problem is that, when the shell does command substitution, any trailing newline characters are deleted.  So, the `\n` in the `printf` format is removed before the output is assigned to `newline`.

That means that when you get to here:

```
echo -e ${final_list[@]}
```

There are no newlines.  The `echo` output all appears on one line.

Now, consider:

```
 #this line give perfect output
 # echo "$newline"
```

That works because `echo` adds its own newline to the output.

#### A simpler script

I don't know the structure of your big project, but, as a possible alternative to the code presented, consider:

```
while read team1 team2
do
     newline=$(printf "%-8.2f\t%-8.2f" "$team1" "$team2")
     final_list=("${final_list[@]}" "$newline")
done <input.txt
printf "%s\n" "${final_list[@]}" | sort -t$'\t' -k1 -n
```

Still simpler, but possibly not helpful in the big project, would be this code which reformats and sorts `input.txt`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%-8.2f\t%-8.2f\n",$1,$2}' input.txt |sort -n
1.12            13.22   
3.01            14.12   
3.01            16.12
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked like charm, I posted question desperately, after long night trying to get output, so just wrote code and answer by self without running that code, I was loosing  %-8.2f too, which I am not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use sort -n to sort the file (if needed redirect it to new file like > newfile.txt and use it)?

```
sort -n input.txt
```

Comment: I did that as my plan B, but I thought reading and writing will make my code slow.